# How to import Chart.js with Webpack

Tags: webpack, chart.js, vue.js

I have a Vue JS project using Webpack and need to import Chart.js. I have tried

```
// import Chart from 'chart.js/Chart.min.js'
```

This gives js errors when trying to use the library.

Answer (score 16):

After you do `npm install chart.js`,

You can simply use

```
import Chart from 'chart.js'
```

to import chart.js
Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I met similar error. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As seen on [this issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/526), if you use Angular CLI you only need to add this to the scripts array in **angular-cli.json**:

```
"../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"
```

Restart your application, live reload won't do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Using webpack, I've found that I had to add `Chart` to the global context like so:

```
// Ensure the Chart class is loaded in the global context
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
window.Chart = Chart
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with all those issues as well, but then I found [this answer to a follow-up trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76362428/9064287). It is well explained and it solved my import problems.