# Symfony 4 - Import ChartJS with webpack encore?

Tags: symfony, class, webpack, charts

I downloaded the ChartJS package on Symfony, and I would like to be able to use it with webpack-encore

In my Twig template, I can use Chart with :

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), { ..... }
```

It works with CDN, but now I would like to use it with webpack-encore.

So in my **app.js** I tried :

```
//1er essai
import Chart from "chart.js";
global.Chart = Chart

//2eme essai
const Chart = require("chart.js");
global.Chart = Chart;
```

But neither works. Each time in the browser I get the following error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: It's possible this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024087/how-to-import-chart-js-with-webpack) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using webpack encore I find it easier to install different modules via npm.
In the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html) it says that bower and npm are recommended.
So you basically write this

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

And for usage you simply [import it.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Yarn (recommended by Webpack Encore), just type :

```
yarn add chart.js
```

Then in your js file :

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';

new Chart($("#myElement"), {
    ...
});
```