# How to Correctly import JS modules - (Nodejs - Express)

Tags: node.js, express, chart.js

I am currently learning to use nodejs with **express** as my franework and **handlebar** as the template engine.

PS: This is from the [chartjs tutorial](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html#build-a-new-application-with-chart-js) where they use **parcel**.

When I am trying to do the same with express (node src/app.js) I am getting an error **Failed to resolve module specifier "chart.js/auto"**

I have noticed couple of times where I am not able to import modules in external js files.
Is there a way to import modules in external js files or is it that express in particular is unable to the same.

I have already npm installed chartjs.
I have a page **index.hbs**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Chart.js example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 800px;"><canvas id="acquisitions"></canvas></div>
    <script type="module" src="./js/acquisitions.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and **acquisitions.js**

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'

(async function() {
  const data = [
    { year: 2010, count: 10 },
    { year: 2011, count: 20 },
    { year: 2012, count: 15 },
    { year: 2013, count: 25 },
    { year: 2014, count: 22 },
    { year: 2015, count: 30 },
    { year: 2016, count: 28 },
  ];

  new Chart(
    document.getElementById('acquisitions'),
    {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: data.map(row => row.year),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Acquisitions by year',
            data: data.map(row => row.count)
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  );
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Importing modules using import maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#importing_modules_using_import_maps)

> [Import maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap) allow developers to instead specify almost any text they want in the module specifier when importing a module; the map provides a corresponding value that will replace the text when the module URL is resolved.

Let's see an example, I will use the HTML file to demonstrate. It's the same for using any template engine.

Directory structure:

```
- project
  - node_modules
    - chart.js
      - auto
      - dist
    - @kurkle
      - color
        - dist
          - color.cjs.js
          - color.d.ts
          - color.esm.js
  - src
    - importmap
      - public
        - js
          - acquisitions.js
      - index.html
```

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules')))
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is listening on http://localhost:3000'))
```

`public/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 800px;"><canvas id="acquisitions"></canvas></div>

  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "@kurkle/color": "/node_modules/@kurkle/color/dist/color.esm.js",
        "chart.js/auto": "/node_modules/chart.js/auto/auto.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script type="module" src="./js/acquisitions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`public/js/acquisitions.js`:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'

(async function () {
  const data = [
    { year: 2010, count: 10 },
    { year: 2011, count: 20 },
    { year: 2012, count: 15 },
    { year: 2013, count: 25 },
    { year: 2014, count: 22 },
    { year: 2015, count: 30 },
    { year: 2016, count: 28 },
  ];

  new Chart(
    document.getElementById('acquisitions'),
    {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: data.map(row => row.year),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Acquisitions by year',
            data: data.map(row => row.count)
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  );
})();
```

`chart.js` use `@kurkle/color` as its dependency, so we must add it to import maps. `chart.js` will use `import '@kurkle/color'` statement to import it.

Start the server and access the `http://localhost:3000` endpoint, result:

[image]